# why netstat -an shows so many TIME_WAIT connections to port 111 from local ports?

Tags: linux, networking, nfs, rhel7, freeipa

I am seeing so many TIME_WAIT connections to port 111 from local ports in my RHEL7.2 workstations.

These client systems are involved in heavy ssh (i.e. automated scripts doing ssh connections). 
Clients also have 15-20 NFS mount-points.

These clients are configured to authenticate user accounts through NIS server (ypbind service).

This setup was working for more than 2-3 years, but recently after migrating from NIS to IPA Server i am getting this problem.

Even i am getting Stale file handle error while listing NFS directories, this happens when no of TIME_WAIT connection reaches near 30000.

I have almost 300 clients and looking for some permanent solution, don't want to do workaround. I have explored few solutions, but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: @kaylum sorry... i saw few linux related queries were answered , so i thought i can. won't be posting these kind of questions again.